# Exporting Golang packages for testing?

Tags: unit-testing, go

In trying to come with test against code that uses the following struct:

```
type DatabaseSt struct {
    DBName            string
    DBConnectionStr   string
    dbConnection      *sql.DB
    InterpolateParams bool

    //Archived Databases
    MinFinancialYear int
    MaxFinancialYear int
}

//DatabaseContext The context to use if the use of a database is needed.
type DatabaseContext struct {
    *Context
    Database DatabaseSt
}
```

I stumbled upon [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@robiplus/golang-trick-export-for-test-aa16cbd7b8cd) claiming that you can export Golang packages, with their internals, in test code. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what they mean in their last words:

> export_test.go only be include when we run go test, so it not pollute your API, and user never access them(not like java’s @VisibleForTesting), and it build a bridge let unexported one accessible in math_test

and even worse, replication of it leads to nowhere fast:

[image]

/* Here, `context` is the package containing the struct I want full access to */

I basically need to be able to set the `dbConnection` of that `DatabaseSt` for testing, without modifying the source code.

Comment: i think you can create a test file with the package name "packagename_test" to achieve that but i am not sure

Comment: `var ContextPkg = context` there doesn't make sense to me...  Have you read https://golang.org/pkg/testing/ and https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages already?

Comment: That article is talking about "black box" testing within the same package, using a different package identifier. I don't understand what the point of testing via an external package name is if you need to export extra pieces to do so. Nearly all code is tested within the same package.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following file named export_test.go:

```
package context

func SetDbConnection(DatabaseSt *ds, db *sql.DB) {
    ds.dbConnection = db
}
```

Use it from other test files in the same directory like this:

```
package context_test

import "context"

func FooTest(t *testing.T) {
     ...
     context.SetDbConnection(ds, db)
     ...
}
```

Alternatively, write the test in the context package so you have full access to the members:

```
package context

func FooTest(t *testing.T) {
     ...
     ds.dbConnection = db
     ...
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but by extending the `DatabaseSt`, with an object called `DatabaseStub`, which contains the mock to assert expectations on (not just the stub database connection), and in a file named `stubDBContext_test.go`. To my horror, the functions that I wrote there couldn't be found. I got these errors all over the place from the test that used the code: 

`undefined: "ezsoft/apiserver_sdk/context".NewDBStub`

Comment: Explain what you mean by "extending".   The trick in this answer only works in the same directory as the package.  Are you trying to access this from another package?

Comment: Yes. There's code althroughout the SUT that uses the `context.DatabaseContext`. By "extending", I mean creating a stub object that **has** the desired `context.DatabaseSt` that the `DatabaseContext` arguments require (but also other fields, like `Mock` for storing expectations on the provided `dbConnection`).